# it is possible to prevent insert/updates in sql relating to 2 different columns in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

im trying to figure out a method sql-side (mysql) to prevent inserting or updating certain data depending on columns.
depending on the data in one column, the other one isnt allowed to have the same and via versa.
for example:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║   Col1    ║   Col2    ║            OK?             ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ 168068786 ║           ║ This is ok                 ║
║           ║ 636435623 ║ This is ok                 ║
║ 536733246 ║ 356367235 ║ This is ok                 ║
║ 526372123 ║ 526372123 ║ This isnt ok (same values) ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

is this possible via constraints? or any other method? i dont quite get how to achieve that if it is indeed possible via constraints.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by TRIGGER-functions called before you are doing the INSERT/UPDATE. Check [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Col1, Col2 
    FROM Tbl 
    WHERE Col1 IN ('Val1', 'Val2') OR Col2 IN ('Val1', 'Val2') 
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thanks, that wasnt what i had in mind though. i wanted to prevent those inserts in general ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using a unique constraint on your table, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_MyTable UNIQUE (Col1, Col2);
```

Then, alter your SQL statement to:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (...)
```

It will avoid the duplicate insertion without showing warnings.

Comment: ahh - if i dont add "IGNORE" into my statement, it should throw errors, right?

Comment: @theblackkey Yes. There will be an error that you would have violated the uniqueness.